# ionic "Runtime Error Maximum call stack size exceeded"

Tags: ionic-framework

I want to create a simple stopwatch app. After I click the blue button to start a stopwatch. It will show the runtime error. This is my code:

[hello-ionic.ts](https://gist.github.com/perrot/09c45979ff09b75030c6fe0440881f2f)

[hello-ionic.html](https://gist.github.com/perrot/137dd38f73a17ce0855e318dc013fe40)

How to fix this problem?Thanks

Comment: You built yourself a nice infinite loop here by recursively calling your `timer()` function and falsly assuming that `setTimeout()` is a synchronous task. This exceeds the js-call-stack pretty fast.

Comment: Thanks David. I replace the setTimeout function with setInterval. It's work.